# Не работает JS в bootstrap на модальное окно

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Я вставил все ссылки для JS и Jquery ,но всё ровно не работает. При нажатие на support вылезает модальное окно и чтобы если человек нажимает вне модального окна оно не закрывалось.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Учу bootstrap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="123.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $('#exampleModal').modal({
      backdrop: "static"
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
      <img src="img/english.png" width="80" height="40" alt="logo" title="Home">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportContent" aria-expend="false" aria-label="ToggleNavigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="bd">Present</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="bd">Past</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="bd">Can, will</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="bd" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Support</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div id="carouselHome" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-target="carouselHome" data-slide-to="0"></li>
        <li class="active" data-target="carouselHome" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li class="active" data-target="carouselHome" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li class="active" data-target="carouselHome" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="img/city1.jpg" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="img/city2.jpg" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="img/city3.jpg" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="img/city4.jpg" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#carouselHome" class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#carouselHome" class="carousel-control-next" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="cntainer">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col">
          <a href="#"><img src="img/1.png" alt="" class="w-25"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <a href="#"><img src="img/2.png" alt="" class="w-25"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <a href="#"><img src="img/3.png" alt="" class="w-25"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Hello world</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы модальное окно не закрывалось при нажатии вне его области, нужно добавить атрибут `data-backdrop="static"` на кнопку вызова модального окна:

```
<a href="#" class="nav-link" id="bd" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-backdrop="static">Support</a>
```

Либо вызывать модальное окно через js с уже явно указанными параметрами:

```
$('#exampleModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static'
});
```

В Вашем примере вызов модального окна не сработает по тому что, сам элемент `#exampleModal` во время выполнения скрипта еще не создан. Нужно переместить код 
в низ страницы или использовать обвертку `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#exampleModal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static'
    });
});
```

Больше об управлении модальными окнами в [документации](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-data-attributes) (**v4.0**)